# How can I create XSD file alongside with XML programmatically without using JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, dom, xsd, jaxb2

I am developing a program where I want to create XSD file alongside the XML file.

Like if XML file updates then XSD file will also be updated instantly.I have written code using DOM approach that creates an XML file and can be updated upon users action.Now I also want to create an XSD file that would be used to validate the XML file at any time and also to define data structure of the XML file.

Is there any way to create XSD file alongside with XML file so that XSD file updates whenever XML file updated using DOM approach??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`xsd-gen`](https://github.com/wiztools/xsd-gen) which allows to generate a `XSD` file from a `XML` file:

```
XsdGen gen = new XsdGen();
gen.parse(new File("in.xml"));
File out = new File("out.xsd");
gen.write(new FileOutputStream(out));
```

The the **current latest version** is `0.2.1` and is available from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wiztools/xsd-gen/0.2.1).

You will also need to add to your classpath/project **all its compile dependencies** which are:

1. [`com.google.code.cli-parser:cli`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.cli-parser/cli/7)
2. [`org.wiztools.commons:wiztools-commons-lib`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wiztools.commons/wiztools-commons-lib/0.4.1)
3. [`xom:xom`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xom/xom/1.2.5)

Comment: I haven't find XsdGen class.Is it from an external library?

Comment: I couldn't import the package after adding the folder as a source folder. It showing package declaration error!!How can I use it?

Comment: as a source folder? why as source folder? download it from here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wiztools/xsd-gen/0.2.1 and add it to your classpath

Comment: While creating XsdGen object It's giving me a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:. how can I fix it?

Comment: Check the compile dependencies listed here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wiztools/xsd-gen/0.2.1 and for each of them download the corresponding jar and add it to your classpath/project